# Getting array keys instead of the value with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm getting a problem while I want to loop through an array and display it with Laravel blade engine

**My controllers code is like this**

```
    $table =  DB::table('tables')->select('id')->where('name', strtolower($name))->first();

    $columns =  Column::where('table_id', $table->id)->get();

    foreach ($columns as $col) {
        $data[] = $col->col_name;
    };

    $content = DB::table($name)->select(...$data)->get();


    return view('back.group.view-table', compact('content', 'columns', 'data'));
```

**And my blade view code is like this**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach($columns as $column)
                        <th>{{ $column->dis_name }}</th>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($content as  $value)
                    <tr>
                        
                        @for ($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++)
                            <td>{{ $value->key = $data[$i] }}</td>
                        @endfor
                        
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is the result which I get with the following code:
[image: This is the result which I get with the following code]

The result I want to have:
[image: The result I want to have]

Comment: $content  as $value then {{ put here your array index name }}

Answer (score 3):

php has a function called [array_keys()](https://www.w3schools.com/pHp/func_array_keys.asp);

so it looks something like this I think

```
$results = DB::table($name)->select(...$data)->get();
$content = $results->first();
$keys = array_keys($content->toArray());
```

this will get you the keys. If you need the keys from each result just loop over $results and for each $result get the keys, using the array_keys syntax.

Comment: There's now also [a laravel collection method simply called `keys`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be using [array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) it will flip the keys and values around.

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
<table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
       <tr>
        @foreach($columns as $column)
          <th>{{ $column->dis_name }}</th>
        @endforeach
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      @foreach ($content as  $value)
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach

     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I know that and i alredy did it but i want the users to get automatically the columns wich are coming from a table selected by the user if u understand

Comment: here foreach loop already do same thing what you want ... once check this

Comment: what i mean is if the table user has columns id username email etc etc i want to be displayed dynamiclly because he will select another table after with different columns ex. products id name price etc etc thats why i want that to be dynamic

Comment: first check $content array value by print_r if loop have more than one value then loop automatically repeat printing tr with its value ...

Comment: `Collection {#196 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#194 ▼
      +"onomateponimo": "Mukja Eluert"
      +"email": "e.mukja@icloud.com"
      +"kinito": "123456789"
    }
    1 => {#190 ▼
      +"onomateponimo": "Eluert "
      +"email": "e.mukja@outlook.com"
      +"kinito": "123456789"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: **And i want user to choose between tables another table output might be like this **

`$content = DB::table('xrister')->select(...$data)->get();
dd($content);`

** Output will be **

`Collection {#180 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#190 ▼
      +"onoma": "Eluert"
      +"epitheto": "Mukja"
    }
    1 => {#195 ▼
      +"onoma": "Exnet"
      +"epitheto": "Hellas"
    }
    2 => {#193 ▼
      +"onoma": "Mukja"
      +"epitheto": "Erti"
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

use `array_keys()` to get all the keys from an array, you also can use `foreach($arr as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer i just change my view from this

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach($columns as $column)
                    <th>{{ $column->dis_name }}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($content as  $value)
                <tr>

                    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++)
                        <td>{{ $value->key = $data[$i] }}</td>
                    @endfor

                </tr>
            @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

To this

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach($columns as $column)
                        <th>{{ $column->dis_name }}</th>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($content as  $value)
                    <tr>

                        @foreach ($data as $key)
                            <td>{{ $value->$key }}</td>
                        @endforeach

                    </tr>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$hayStack = ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 30, 'sex' => 'm'];
$searchValue = 30;
$keyName = array_keys($hayStack, $searchValue)[0];
```

array_keys() will search all possible keys containing search value. Considering `$hayStack` to be an array, there won't be any duplicate key, so our result will be at index 0.
For search value is 30, result will be 'age'.
Here array_keys is an inbuilt function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! Please explain your solution and ideally add references to the docs. I don't think the poster can understand it as you wrote it.